# Error while deploying java webservice

Tags: java, tomcat, web-services, apache-axis

Could someone help me on this.

I have created simple java web service using Java 1.6, tomcat-6.0.20 and axis2-1.4.1.

While deploying the application, it returns following error message:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Feb 25, 2010 11:58:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that there is an incompatibility of libraries loaded.

See this [post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200710.mbox/%3C13019854.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) and [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Apache/Q_23571438.html)

The first post explain the error:

> > In Tomcat 6, the JSP API classes are found in jsp-api.jar and servlet
> >     API classes are found in servlet-api.jar, with both located in the lib
> >     directory of the Tomcat 6 installation.  Any servlet.jar you find
> >     involved with this server would contain out of date classes for this
> >     server.

So... check if you don't have an extra servlet.jar:

> Make sure you don't
>   have a copy of servlet.jar in the WEB-INF/lib of your webapp or
>   somewhere else involved with the running server, such as in the
>   lib/ext directory of your JDK or JRE.

I hope it helps you.